# GreenDao. N:M relation

Tags: android, database, orm, many-to-many, greendao

i've just started to use GreenRobot ORM and stacked with DB creation. I need to create N:M relation between two tables. Official doc. says they still dont support N:M, so I have to implement this by my own.

So, lets imagine I have 2 entities: *Exercise* and *Accessories*. They look like:

```
Entity accessories = schema.addEntity("Accessories");
        accessories.addIdProperty();
        accessories.addStringProperty("name").unique().notNull();
        accessories.addStringProperty("desc");
Entity exercise = schema.addEntity("Exercise");
        exercise.addIdProperty();
        exercise.addStringProperty("name");
        exercise.addStringProperty("desc");
        exercise.addByteProperty("level");
```

And now I want to create another entity *Exercise_Accessories*, which contains ids of these entities above. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, that you must create a middle entity that holds references to the id's of the objects you want to link in N:M relationship.

Create an entity and get the properties of the id's:

```
Entity exerciseAccesories = schema.addEntity("ExercisesAccesories")
exerciseAccesories.addIdProperty();
Property exerciseId = exerciseAccesories.addLongProperty("exercise").getProperty();
Property accessoryId = exerciseAccesories.addLongProperty("accessory").getProperty();
```

And then [link the properties](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/#Many-to-Many_Relations_nm#Modelling_To-Many_Relations):

```
accessories.addToMany(exerciseAccesories, accessoryId).setName("accessoryRef");
exercise.addToMany(exerciseAccesories, exerciseId).setName("exerciseRef");
```

Mead more about [SQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/) as this is a standard way to model many-to-many relationships.

Of course this entity row is not added automatically to the database, when adding entity and accessory. You need to insert it manually.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just 1 more question - should I use ORM in a simple application or it will be enough just to use Google API?

Comment: By GoogleAPI you mean standard Android SQLite framework? You can, but remember, that in such case all SQL statements must be written by you. GreenDao is more simple as it helps you do that in code (not touching SQL), however only standard select's or insert's can be done. For example you can only query for whole objects not their specific properties.

Comment: I meant "Cursor", ok, thank you again. I'm gonna give ORM a try :]
Have a good day.